# Cruising with an infant

Tags: usa, children, cruising

I'm looking to go on a cruise leaving from New York but have a concern because if I go I will be traveling with a 4 month old infant.

The question is whether the cruise ships are actually equipped to handle infants of that age?

And what are some of the practical considerations I should consider when cruising with child that age?

Comment: equipped how? Is your issue where the baby will sleep? Do you want to know if they will provide food or are you nursing? Do you need facilities to wash diapers? Please elaborate on what you need to know about the ship.

Comment: Basically a crib or bassinet, or space to keep a stroller.  Food will most likely be brought with us.

Comment: You might want to edit that into the question. It's been flagged as unclear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I searched for infant in the [Carnival FAQs](http://www.carnival.com/core/faq.aspx) and found the following (in order of relevance to you)

- **Minimum age for sailing is 6 months**, with the exceptions of Transatlantic, Hawaii and South American cruises, which are 12 months.
- Cribs are provided complimentary in staterooms.
- The onboard nonfree childcare will accept (to a limited extent) children under 2 and children in diapers, and will change diapers if you provide them.
- no child in a diaper is allowed in a pool, whirlpool, water slide etc
- Baby food and formula is not available onboard.

So it seems your answer on Carnival is NO. They're not equipped and you're not allowed. I didn't search other cruise lines, but since the rationale for not allowing them is worry that such a small baby could get sick very quickly, I suspect you'll find the same elsewhere.

Comment: Royal Caribbean ( http://www.royalcaribbean.com/customersupport/faq/details.do?pagename=frequently_asked_questions&faqId=309&faqSubjectId=333) has the same minimun age policy. Babies should be at least 6 months old.

Answer (score 1):

Disney Cruise Line also disallows children under 6 months (or 12 months for certain longer itineraries) beginning last year.

http://disneycruiselineblog.com/2014/07/disney-cruise-lines-infant-policy-changes-effective-7182014/